# What is the type alias rules in Scala?

Tags: scala

So, just can't understand why does this compiles?

```
  type <=[B, A] = A => B 
  type F[A] = Double <= A //why our alias <= is allowed here?
```

What is the syntax rule of forming type aliases which allows constructions like these?
Can we free play only with the order => here like in this case?

Comment: _"why our alias <= is allowed here?"_ why not? - _"What is the rule of forming type aliases which allows constructions like these?"_ I don't understand this question. - _"Can we free play only with the order => here like in this case?"_ again, I don't understand.

Comment: **<=** is a type alias, **=>** - look like operator which we can use to bind types in sequences. I do not understand why _"type alias"_ in second line is readed by compiler as an operator, which can bind together two types. I see no reason...

Comment: `<=` is a type, `=>` is a type, there are no operators there because the language doesn't have any operators at all _(except for assignment `=`)_

Comment: I could not find definition of `=>`, and that is why its an enigma for me, how Scala compiler parse an alias expression like sequence of types `Type1 Type2 Type3` as in this example is. Where can I get more info about how Scala parse this type aliases?

Comment: In my case I dont know how does compiler parse `Double <= A`. Looks like it is not simple substitution to `Double A => B A`

Comment: https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#infix-types

Answer (score 4):

There is a very simple rule that every type `A B C` is the same as `B[A, C]`. Evidently this only works for types with 2 type parameters.

Answer (score 2):

> I could not find the definition of =>

Yeah, it is embedded in the compiler implementation / language specification.
But, as you just show, it is quite easy to reimplement in on userland; it would look like this:

```scala
type =>[+A, +B] = Function1[A, B]
```

> how Scala compiler parse an alias expression like sequence of types Type1 Type2 Type3

The language specs say that it supports infix types, so things like: `A OP B` are equivalent to `OP[A, B]`

Comment: uff.. forgot about infix notations... Did not mention that infix rules can work with types as well. Thank you. It becomes much more clear!